# Enupal Backup not backing up assets

Tags: back-up

I am testing Enupal Backup.

In the settings, I can choose to back up assets, templates, etc. But when I run the backup, only the database is acutally backed up.

What am I missing here?

I [submitted an issue](https://github.com/enupal/backup/issues/30) regarding this at the repo, in case it's a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glad to know that it is working on your server. On Windows, you may need to add the paths manually. Please follow [our docs](https://docs.enupal.com/enupal-backup/advanced-settings/paths.html) about how to add the paths on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe consider using https://phpbu.de/ directly. It's pretty easy to setup with the phar and a config file. Saves the license fee as well.